# $output for the name not value

Tags: php, output

I am using multiple choice in html:

```
<form target="POPUPW"
onsubmit="POPUPW = window.open('about:blank','POPUPW','width=400,height=400');" name="search1" action="popresult.php" method="POST">


       <b>အကၡရာ</b>
                <select name="pre">
        <option value="c1">က</option>
        <option value="c2">ခ</option>
        <option value="c3">ဂ</option>
        <option value="c4">ဃ</option>
        <option value="c5">င</option>
        <option value="c6">စ</option>
        <option value="c7">ဆ</option>
        <option value="c8">ဇ</option>
        <option value="c9">စ်</option>
        <option value="c10">ည</option>
        <option value="c11">ဋ</option>
        <option value="c12">ဌ</option>
        <option value="c13">ဍ</option>
        <option value="c14">ဎ</option>
        <option value="c15">ဏ</option>
        <option value="c16">တ</option>
        <option value="c17">ထ</option>
        <option value="c18">ဒ</option>
        <option value="c19">ဓ</option>
        <option value="c20">န</option>
        <option value="c21">ပ</option>
        <option value="c22">ဖ</option>
        <option value="c23">ဗ</option>
        <option value="c24">ဘ</option>
        <option value="c25">မ</option>
        <option value="c26">ယ</option>
        <option value="c27">ရ</option>
        <option value="c28">လ</option>
        <option value="c29">၀</option>
        <option value="c30">သ</option>
        <option value="c31">ဟ</option>
        <option value="c32">ဠ</option>
        <option value="c33">အ</option>
        <option value="c34">ကက</option>
        <option value="c35">ကခ</option>
        <option value="c36">ကဂ</option>
        <option value="c37">ကဃ</option>
        <option value="c38">ကင</option>
        <option value="c39">ကစ</option>
        <option value="c40">ကဆ</option>
                </select>

        <b>Number</b>
                <select name="one">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <select name="two">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <select name="three">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <select name="four">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <select name="five">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
        <select name="six">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>

                <input type="submit" name="search" value="ထီတိုက္ရန္" style="font-family:Zawgyi-One;" />

        </form>
```

my php is

```
            <?php
        $output = NULL;

        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","searchdemo") or die("Unable to select database" . mysqli_error($link));

        if(isset($_POST['search'])){
            $spre = $_POST['pre'];
            $sone = $_POST['one'];
            $stwo = $_POST['two'];
            $sthree = $_POST['three'];
            $sfour = $_POST['four'];
            $sfive = $_POST['five'];
            $ssix = $_POST['six'];

            $query = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM `346` WHERE pre = '$spre' AND one = '$sone' AND two = '$stwo' AND three = '$sthree' AND four = '$sfour' AND five = '$sfive' AND six = '$ssix'") or die("<b>Error</b> : ".mysqli_error($link));
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);


    if ($count == 0){

        $output = 'Try Again';


    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            extract($row);

            $price = $row['price'];

            $output = '<style="font-family:Zawgyi-One">ဂုဏ္ယူ၀မ္းေျမာက္ပါတယ္ခင္ဗ်ာ ... <br />လူႀကီးမင္းဟာ ယခုဆို သိန္းေပါင္း ' .$price. 'ကို ဆြတ္ခူးသြားႏိုင္ပါၿပီ</style>';
        }

    }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    You are searching for <b style="font-family:Zawgyi-One"><?php echo $spre; ?> - <?php echo $sone; ?><?php echo $stwo; ?><?php echo $sthree; ?><?php echo $sfour; ?><?php echo $sfive; ?><?php echo $ssix; ?></b><br /><br />
    </html>
<?php
    print ("$output <br />");
?>
```

But when I search, the result was shown in

> You are searching for c1 - 000000

But I like to show "c1" as က (က is unicode). And I will import CSV file into my database without including unicode.

Comment: you can use push() method in php, to store each value.

Comment: *"I am using multiple choice in html:"* - well then, you need to `foreach` and you need to show full code for your form and PHP including if you are using the proper syntax for it.

Comment: This question is as clear as mud at midnight. No way to give a full solution until we see the full and actual code used to process this.

Answer (score 2):

The content of the `value=""` is what the Browser send to PHP, if you want to see exactly whats in the option then code it like

```
<select name="name">
   <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
   <option value="Micheal">Micheal</option>
   <option value="Sean">Sean</option>
</select>
```

However it is normal to code something like an `id` in the `value="<?php echo $id;?>"` as then you can retrieve the data associated with the name more easily.

Ah I just noticed that you said you were using multiple choice or wanted too at least.

In that case you need to change the `<select>` tag like so

```
<select name="name" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="Joe">Joe</option>
   <option value="Micheal">Micheal</option>
   <option value="Sean">Sean</option>
</select>
```

Then in your PHP code the `$_POST['name']` variable will be returned as an array, so you would processing like this :-

```
if ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $_POST['name'] as $selected_name ) {
        echo $selected_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: importing CSV into MySQL is not supported unicode. So i can't set `value` same with names.

Comment: Sorry Si I dont understand, where did importing CSV into mysql come into the question